# Instead of executing evaluation expression, mvc controller method is being executing - Spring Web Flow

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am newbee in Spring Web Flow. I have created a sample project using spring web flow. From the home page, mvc controller method is executing as per the expectation and reaching second page. From second page, on click of submit one evaluation expression has to be executed. Instead of that the method which executed first is executing again.
I could see that the action on the form is only ${flowExecutionUrl} . So RequestMapping is getting the same url. Therefore executing the old method.

1. Is it possible to change uri in action  attribute and then append ${flowExecutionUrl}.
2. How can we make sure that the flow definition file is being executing

Servlet-context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.metlife.claim"/>
    <bean class=
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /claim/=flowController
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    </bean>
        <bean class=
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <bean class=
"org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
       <bean id="viewResolver" class=
"org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
        <bean id="flowController" class=
"org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    </bean>
        <flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>
        <flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
            flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <flow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/claims-flow.xml"/>
    </flow:flow-registry>

    <flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"
            view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator"/>

    <bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class=
"org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="viewResolver"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

claim-flow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- <view-state id="claims" view="addClaims"> -->
    <view-state id="claims" model = "viewScope.claim">
    <transition to="claimsEntered" on="submit">
        <!-- <evaluate expression="claimController.saveNewClaim(viewScope.claim)"></evaluate> -->
        </transition>
        </view-state>
    <action-state id="claimsEntered">
    <evaluate expression="claimController.saveNewClaim(viewScope.claim)"></evaluate>
    <transition to="claims"></transition>
    </action-state>
</flow>
```

ClaimController.java

```
@Controller
public class ClaimController {

    public static List<Claim> claimList = new ArrayList<Claim>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/claims/")
    public void getClaims(){
        System.out.println("Hi Claims");
    }

    public void saveNewClaim(Claim claim){
        claimList.add(claim);
        System.out.println("The claim has been added...");
    }
}
```

claims.jsp

```
<form modelAttribute = "claim" action= "${flowExecutionUrl}">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td><input type = "text" path="id" name = "id"/></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type = "text" path="id" name = "name"/></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Age</td>
<td><input type = "text" path="id" name = "age"/></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Amount</td>
<td><input type = "text" path="id" name = "amount"/></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Region</td>
<td><input type = "text" path="id" name = "region"/></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type = "submit" id = "submit" name = "_eventId_submit" value = "Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

home.jsp

```
<body>
<h1>
</h1>
<P> <a href="claims/" >Claims</a> </P>
</body>
```

On the click event of Submit button from claims.jsp, it is executing getClaims() method of the ClaimController instead of saveNewClaim().

Can anybody please help to identify what is wrong with the implementation , how can resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about claim-flow.xml but you can use RequestMapping in saveNewClaim method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/claims/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveNewClaim(Claim claim){
    claimList.add(claim);
    System.out.println("The claim has been added...");
}
```

I was thinking about sth like this:

```
@Controller
public class ClaimController {

    public static List<Claim> claimList = new ArrayList<Claim>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/claims/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getClaims(){
        System.out.println("Hi Claims");
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/claims/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveNewClaim(Claim claim){
        claimList.add(claim);
        System.out.println("The claim has been added...");
    }
}
```

First method load the form. The second respond for POST request from this form.

Comment: Yes. You are right in the case of Spring MVC. If we are specifying RequestMapping with value, Web-flow is not coming into the picture